# My find/replace text magically changes in Xcode

Tags: xcode, google-chrome, search

I had a project wide find/replace search all set up yesterday in my Xcode project. Today when I get back to Xcode (without restarting or touching it in any way) the search text has changed. The weirdest thing is that the search text is now the same as a text search I made today in Google Chrome(!). I know for a fact that I haven't searched for "shipping costs" in my Xcode project.

Could someone explain what's going on? I don't particularly like it when applications throw away my data and I would like to prevent this from happening again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find/replace uses what's known as the Kill Ring, rather than regular Copy/Paste

It's similar to the regular Copy/Paste buffers, but uses a separate memory area.

You can 'Kill' using  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  which is similar to Cut &
'Yank' using  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>  which is like Paste.

The kill ring is also used in a lot of search routines, so will be replaced any time you perform a new search.
Don't rely on it as a data store.

Comment: Interesting, but I can't get those shortcuts to work and it seems difficult to find any documentation on this feature. I can't see the beauty of find/replace using either the kill ring or the clipboard to store the data in though...

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/01/use-a-secondary-cut-and-paste-function-to-avoid-overwriting-clipboard-contents/