# How do I make searching unique per application or window?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, iterm, search

I have iTerm2 and Chrome open.

In iTerm2 I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search for "###".

Then in Chrome I search for something on the page using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> like the word "event"

When I go back to iTerm2, the search window has "event" in it instead of "###".  Likewise for Chrome, when I go back there after fixing the iTerm2 search, it now has "###" in the search bar.

The issue is more than just having to retype my search every time. When I search in Chrome, it begins an active search in iTerm2 that I didn't tell it to search for.  It's annoying switching back to iTerm2 and seeing yellow highlighting all over for things I didn't search for there.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220317/my-find-replace-text-magically-changes-in-xcode?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround specific to iTerm2:

For iTerm2 you can use `Shift+Command+F` which opens a "Find Globally" search which is private to iTerm2.  It is 'global' in the sense that it searches all the open iTerm2 windows and tabs.

This solves your problem with iTerm2 and any single other app, but doesn't generalise to any app.

Comment: This does work, though comes with its own set of issues.  My ### was actually a printout with 200 #'s, so searching for ### gives me 198 matches, each one being a line in the matching window.  I do like how it centralizes all of the matches.